# am getting this error when i try to launch profile screen

Tags: flutter

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
> The following LateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<DataManagerProvider?>], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#92f1f):
> LateInitializationError: Field 'photographerProfile' has not been initialized.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was: 
> StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder:file:///C:/Users/RANGO/StudioProjects/photography/lib/screens/photographer/photographer_dashboard.dart:101:18
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
> #0      DataManagerProvider.photographerProfile (package:photography/data%20manager/data_manager.dart)
> #1      DataManagerProvider.getPhotographerProfile (package:photography/data%20manager/data_manager.dart:54:51)
> #2      _PhotographerDashboardState.build.. (package:photography/screens/photographer/photographer_dashboard.dart:107:24)
> #3      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:444:81)
> #4      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:48)
> #5      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5080:27)
> #6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:15)
> #7      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5133:11)
> #8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:5)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind formatting your code using backticks (`\``)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable on the file: `../lib/screens/photographer/photographer_dashboard.dart`

Line 101, Column 18

`late photographerProfile...`

that is used as a late initialization but is used without being initialized first. currently, flutter has no way to check if a variable has been initialized so maybe you could make it nullable instead?